# Parenthesis on Numbers Being Treated as Strings and Concatenated

Tags: angular, typescript

The html code specifies that `input1` and `input2` should both be of type `number` and the addition of the numbers should be accomplished by the parenthesis of `(item.input1 + item.input2)` below:

```
   <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="item.input1" type="number"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="item.input2" type="number"></td>
      <td>{{ (item.input1 + item.input2) }}</td>
    </tr>
```

but when a user types in, say `6` below, they are being treated as strings and concatenated. Why and how to resolve?

[image]

---

###### Type Declaration

```
export type NumberArray = Array<{ input1: number; input2: number; }>;
```

###### Array Initialization

```
export class TableViewComponent {
  
  items: NumberArray = [
    { input1:  0, input2: 0 },
    { input1: 1, input2: 2 },
    { input1: 3, input2: 4 },
    { input1: 5, input2: 6 }
  ];
}
```

###### Versions

[image]

###### StackBlitz vs localhost treats input field differently

This is a side issue brought up in the comments, I'm guessing that StackBlitz uses a different angular version. ?

[image]

Comment: add a `+` to the first input: `{{ (+item.input1 + item.input2) }}`

Comment: which angular version are you running, I am not able to reproduce this issue ?

cf https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vblnqw?file=src/main.ts

Comment: @Ninii Angular 15. @Eliseo `(+item.input1 + +item.input2)` works. Is that a reasonable way to cast in Angular?

Comment: `input.value` is *always* of type string! Even if it's an `<input type="number" >` or `<input type="date">`, doesn't matter. Check out `input.valueAsNumber`.

Comment: use the `+` "to cast" is reasonable always you be sure that the "input" is a number. As your input are of type number, I feel that it's ok

Comment: @Thomas I get what you are saying, but unclear how one would apply `valueAsNumber` in the above context.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan nevermind, I typed too quick and didn't look too close. That's a HTML-DOM thing not ngModel.

Comment: @Ninii on StackBlitz the input fields have the numeric up/down option when one types , but on my machine's input field page, they are not numeric up/down. That is weird.